# Get first and last day of week for a couple of weeks

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to make a calendar in which the user can scroll between  several weeks. The first and last day of the week will be displayed like (e.g.) "June 4 - June 10".

Now I knew from the beginning that I'd need `NSDate` and `NSCalendar`, and indeed I managed to get the first and last day of just thist week, but it looks extremely cumbersome and I am sure there needs to be an easier method, as I need to get the dates for several more coming and past weeks.
 This is my code which gives the `day` and `month` of the first and last day of the current week:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *beginOfWeek = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -1*([comp weekday]-2)*24*3600];
    NSDate *endOfWeek = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:(7-[comp weekday]+2)*24*3600];

    NSLog(@"beginWeekDay=%d\n",[[cal components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: beginOfWeek] day]);
    NSLog(@"endWeekDay=%d\n",[[cal components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: endOfWeek] day]);
    NSLog(@"beginWeekmonth=%d\n",[[cal components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: beginOfWeek] month]);
    NSLog(@"endWeekmonth=%d\n",[[cal components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: endOfWeek] month]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, which may be helpful to you: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/11/add-one-week-skip-weekend/

```
- (NSDate *)addWeekToDateAndSkipWeekend:(NSDate *)now {
int daysToAdd = 6; // we'll add the 7th later

// set up date components
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:daysToAdd];

// create a calendar
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];

[components setDay:1]; // reuse to skip single days
NSDateComponents *newDateComps; // new componets to get weekday

// do always executed once, so we add the 7th day here
do
{
    // add one day
    newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:newDate options:0];
    newDateComps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:newDate];

    // repeat if the date is Saturday (7) or Sunday (1)
    NSLog(@"weekday: %d", [newDateComps weekday]);
} while (([newDateComps weekday]==7)||([newDateComps weekday]==1));

return newDate;
}
```

Theoretically, you run this in a for loop with [NSDate date] and you will get the `7th` day returned, you would then run the returned `7th` day through this and get the next..etc..

May need minor alteration, to remove the check for Saturday+Sunday if you don't need it.

Hope this helps !